# How to count number of items without ignoring the doubles in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I have to write a measure that counts the number of bills. Each person gets a bill for every sport they do.

My measure partially works. It does the count of bills, but it is a distinct value. If two (or more) people have the same sport, the doubled sport is ignored.

How do you write this function to count the number of sports people do, without ignoring doubles?

For example, John does football and taekwondo, Ella does taekwondo and tennis. The solution on the question of how many bills are needed should be 4, but I get 3 because taekwondo is ignored.

And one more thing - the future user score needs to be equal to the current user score, that's why I have that filter in measure, but it is irrelevant to the issue so that can be ignored:

My code:

```
CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(
            VALUES(Users[Sports])
        ),
        FILTER(
            VALUES(Users[Sports]),
            CALCULATE(
                COUNTROWS(
                    FILTER(
                        'Users',
                        Users[Current Score] = Users[Future Score]
                    )
                )
            ) > 0
        )
    )
```

Table has four columns:

| Name | Sports | Current Score | Future Score |

Answer (score 1):

VALUES is creating a distinct count so just remove it. e.g.

```
CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(
            Users
        ),
        FILTER(
            VALUES(Users[Sports]),
            CALCULATE(
                COUNTROWS(
                    FILTER(
                        'Users',
                        Users[Current Score] = Users[Future Score]
                    )
                )
            ) > 0
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hmm I tried to remove value where you did, then I tried to remove both values , but - or I get an error or the result is not good - too big. Could you maybe test it?

Comment: It all depends on your data model. Do you have a sample.pbix you can upload somewhere and share a link?